# Unable to locate element with in selenium using xpath written in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to automate an iCal download from this website: webuntis.dk using python and selenium. So far I have managed to get get python to enter the credentials of au_health on the login site. Next I need it to press the small calendar icon in the top right corner. It keeps returning:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/a[@id="Timetable_toolbar_icalButton"]"}
```

My code is as follow:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/juliushvidt/Desktop/chromedriver')

browser.get('https://webuntis.dk/WebUntis/login.do')


username = browser.find_element_by_id("school")

username.send_keys("au_health")


NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH = '//input[@type="submit"]'
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath(NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH)
button.click()

browser.get('https://webuntis.dk/WebUntis/index.do#Timetable?type=3&id=1140')

driver = browser

time.sleep(5.5) #this did the trick

NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH = '//button[@id="Timetable_toolbar_icalButton"]' #using the current button notation was definitely also contributing :)
button = browser.find_element_by_xpath(NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH)
button.click()
```

The inspecting the element im trying to reach on the website I get the following source code:

[image]

Hope you can point me in the right direction as I'm at a loss.

Code exert from the source of the website:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-attach-point="_toolbarContainer" class="dijitContentPane toolbarContainer dijitBorderContainerNoGutter-child dijitBorderContainerNoGutter-dijitContentPane dijitBorderContainerNoGutterPane dijitAlignTop" data-dojo-props="region: 'top'" id="dijit_layout_ContentPane_0" widgetid="dijit_layout_ContentPane_0" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute; width: 31px;"><div class="grupetWidgetToolbar" id="Timetable_toolbar" widgetid="Timetable_toolbar"><div class="grupetWidgetLabelPanel" id="grupet_widget_LabelPanel_0" widgetid="grupet_widget_LabelPanel_0" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div class="grupetWidgetLabelPanelText_ABOVE" data-dojo-attach-point="textNode">Fag</div>
    <div class="grupetWidgetLabelPanelContainer_ABOVE" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"><div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitValidationTextBox" id="widget_Timetable_toolbar_elementSelect" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" data-dojo-attach-point="_popupStateNode" widgetid="Timetable_toolbar_elementSelect"><div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode" role="presentation"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="button presentation" aria-hidden="true"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" tabindex="0" id="Timetable_toolbar_elementSelect" aria-required="false" value="1. sem. Medicinsk filosofi forelæsning" aria-invalid="false"><span class="dijitPlaceHolder dijitInputField" style="display: none;">Vælg her</span><input type="hidden" value="1140"></div></div></div>
</div><div class="grupetWidgetLabelPanel" id="grupet_widget_LabelPanel_1" widgetid="grupet_widget_LabelPanel_1" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div class="grupetWidgetLabelPanelText_ABOVE" data-dojo-attach-point="textNode">Afdeling</div>
    <div class="grupetWidgetLabelPanelContainer_ABOVE" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"><div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft grupetWidgetHasResetButton dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitValidationTextBox" id="widget_Timetable_toolbar_elementFilter_IDC_ABTEILUNG" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" data-dojo-attach-point="_popupStateNode" widgetid="Timetable_toolbar_elementFilter_IDC_ABTEILUNG"><div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode" role="presentation"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="button presentation" aria-hidden="true"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode grupetWidgetResetButton grupetWidgetResetButtonContainer grupetDisplayNone">
    <input type="text" role="presentation" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value=" " title="Nulstil" class="dijitReset dijitInputField grupetWidgetResetButtonInner">
</div><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" tabindex="0" id="Timetable_toolbar_elementFilter_IDC_ABTEILUNG" aria-required="false" value="" aria-invalid="false"><span class="dijitPlaceHolder dijitInputField">Vælg her</span><input type="hidden" value=""></div></div></div>
</div><div class="grupetWidgetLabelPanel" id="grupet_widget_LabelPanel_2" widgetid="grupet_widget_LabelPanel_2" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div class="grupetWidgetLabelPanelText_ABOVE" data-dojo-attach-point="textNode">Aktuel uge</div>
    <div class="grupetWidgetLabelPanelContainer_ABOVE" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode"><div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft date-week-select dijitTextBox dijitComboBox dijitDateTextBox dijitValidationTextBox" id="widget_timetablePageToolbar_dateWeekSelect" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" data-dojo-attach-point="_popupStateNode" widgetid="timetablePageToolbar_dateWeekSelect"><div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode" role="presentation"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" value="▼ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="button presentation" aria-hidden="true"></div><div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" value="Χ " type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" role="presentation"></div><span role="button" class="fa fa-caret-right"></span><span role="button" class="fa fa-caret-left"></span><div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer"><input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" tabindex="0" id="timetablePageToolbar_dateWeekSelect" value="04/12/2017" aria-invalid="false"><input type="hidden" value="2017-12-04"></div></div></div>
</div><span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline gp-iconfont-button dijitDropDownButton" widgetid="Timetable_toolbar_settingsButton" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; float: right;"><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:__onClick" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode"><span class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents dijitDownArrowButton" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode,titleNode,_arrowWrapperNode,_popupStateNode" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="Timetable_toolbar_settingsButton_label" tabindex="0" id="Timetable_toolbar_settingsButton" aria-disabled="false" style="user-select: none;"><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon fa fa-2x fa-cog" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" id="Timetable_toolbar_settingsButton_label"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitArrowButtonInner"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitArrowButtonChar">▼</span></span></span><input type="button" value="" class="dijitOffScreen" tabindex="-1" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></span><button type="button" class="gp-iconfont-button fa fa-2x fa-print" id="Timetable_toolbar_printButton" title="Udskriftsversion" aria-label="Udskriftsversion" widgetid="Timetable_toolbar_printButton" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; float: right;"></button><button type="button" class="icon-ical-24 imageButton imageButtonFocused dijitFocused" title="ICS kalender" aria-label="ICS kalender" id="Timetable_toolbar_icalButton" widgetid="Timetable_toolbar_icalButton" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; float: right;"><div class="icon icon-ical-24"></div></button></div></div>
```

Comment: Please copy/paste the code you're seeing rather than embedding a screenshot. Text makes it easier for people to understand your issue and provide helpful answers.

Comment: I would love to. The source becomes too long to include directly unfortunately, and I believe my problem lies within the website structure instead of the attribute that I'm searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only a single slash, XPATH doesn't look down the tree. To do that you need to use two slashes. Also, the source in your image shows that you are trying to reach a `<button>` element. Try this instead.

```
NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH = '//button[@id="Timetable_toolbar_icalButton"]'
```

EDIT:
I see that parts of the page is dynamically loaded, so you explicitly need to wait for the button to be added to the page. The following should do the trick:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

...

NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH = '//button[@id="Timetable_toolbar_icalButton"]'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
condition = expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH))
button = wait.until(condition)
button.click()
```

NOTE: Using `time.sleep(5.5)` will probably work in some circumstances, but not always as it is dependent on the time used to render the page. Using WebDriverWait will ensure that:

1. You are not dependent on timing.
2. The code returns as soon as the element is available.

Some tips: In the Chrome developer console you can test your xpath expresssions. To do this first go to the Elements tab. Then press `Ctrl+F`. Then you can enter your xpath expression to test it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I have tried previously with // and many other variations I could find. I think that perhaps the element I am trying to click might be located within some sub CSS element that might stop XPATH from finding it. I've looked through all the different comments online I've been able to find on the topic to no avail. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Took a quicker look at your screenshot and saw that the element you are trying to get is a button. Updated my answer to take that into account. As @DanBron mentioned in his comment above, please include the source code and not an image in future posts. If the complete source is to long, use some service like pastebin or similar. At least, include an extract in the question.

Comment: I cannot tell you how much I appreciate your answer. I have now inserted an exert of the specific block of code that deals with the button in question (small calendar icon). I have also tested the proposed new code to no avail. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out it was a timing issue. Testing this with a:

time.sleep(5.5)

and it downloaded the file correctly. Thank you for all the help I received. Without it I am certain I couldn't have figured it out. Cheers :).

Comment: Using `sleep()` is a bad practice. You should replace it with `WebDriverWait`.